# Summing column that is grouped - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a query:

```
SELECT
 date,
 COUNT(o.row_number)FILTER (WHERE o.row_number > 1 AND date_ddr IS NOT NULL AND telephone_number <> 'Anonymous' ) repeat_calls_24h
  (
  SELECT
  telephone_number,
  date_ddr,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ddr.telephone_number ORDER BY ddr.date) row_number,
  FROM
  table_a
  )o
GROUP BY 1
```

Generating the following table:

| date | Repeat calls_24h |
| --- | --- |
| 17/09/2022 | 182 |
| 18/09/2022 | 381 |
| 19/09/2022 | 81 |
| 20/09/2022 | 24 |
| 21/09/2022 | 91 |
| 22/09/2022 | 110 |
| 23/09/2022 | 231 |

What can I add to my query to provide a sum of the previous three days as below?:

| date | Repeat calls_24h | Repeat Calls 3d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17/09/2022 | 182 |  |
| 18/09/2022 | 381 |  |
| 19/09/2022 | 81 | 644 |
| 20/09/2022 | 24 | 486 |
| 21/09/2022 | 91 | 196 |
| 22/09/2022 | 110 | 225 |
| 23/09/2022 | 231 | 432 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it using `lag`.

```
select  "date"
       ,"Repeat calls_24h"
       ,"Repeat calls_24h" + lag("Repeat calls_24h") over(order by "date") + lag("Repeat calls_24h", 2) over(order by "date") as "Repeat Calls 3d"
from    t
```

| date | Repeat calls_24h | Repeat Calls 3d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-17 | 182 | null |
| 2022-09-18 | 381 | null |
| 2022-09-19 | 81 | 644 |
| 2022-09-20 | 24 | 486 |
| 2022-09-21 | 91 | 196 |
| 2022-09-22 | 110 | 225 |
| 2022-09-23 | 231 | 432 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XjvcKusm)